# How to plot the phase response of a transfer function

Tags: signal-processing, phase, phase-shift

I am trying to plot the phase response of a box with an unknown transfer function by by measuring the phase difference between the input and output at different frequencies but I am not exactly sure of how to plot the phase response with the data obtained.

So I have added a table below with the data that shows the phase shift at different frequencies and whether it is the output or input that is leading. If anybody knows how to plot the phase response using this information their help will be very much appreciated.

[image: The table]

Comment: For all leading Output, have the phase value as positive and for all leading Input cases, have it as negative. Plot frequency along x-axis and phase along y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed inverted phase above breakpoint.  But this entire plot could be inverted.

Note the Log f scale, inserted major grid and lighter minor grid, manual scale min:max for both axis.. using XY scatter plot scalc.exe from free Open Office.

This takes 10 minutes to create this format, then you can save template so next time only takes 1 minute.

[image]